# EF Core proper way to delete uncommitted migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Environment: .NET Core 3.1 with EF Core

Short story: two migrations (A and B) were made. B is based on A. But `update-database` has not been executed for both A & B. A was deleted. Is there a way to revert A & B?

Long story: I think I did something stupid. I added a class in the code, then did `add-migration` (let's say it's migration A). After inspecting the generated migration class, I went back to make some changes. Because I haven't run `update-database` yet, I deleted migration A, then ran another `add-migration`, got migration B. Then I found out B is based on A. Deletion of migration A doesn't clear the migration.

Further research I found the migrations, even not updated to database, are kept in the `MyDBContextModelSnapshot.cs` file. Is that's how EF keeps track of it? I can't run `update-database` now because migration A is missing. Applying migration B will just cause an error in database.

My question is, instead of going into `MyDBContextModelSnapshot.cs` and manually revert it to before migration A and redo a migration, is there a way to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: remove migration history from you database (for migration A). then, remove migration B and create it again to be sure that's ok. if migration A has affected your tables, you need to "undo" manually

Comment: In general you should use `Remove-Migration` command instead of manually deleting migration files. That manual file deletion has been used in EF6, but EF Core system is very different. You can try that command to see if it will remove `B` and restore the state. Most probably not (it would have data from `A`), but you could then manually edit the snapshot.

Comment: How did you delete the migration, just deleted the files?  Did you try `dotnet ef database remove B` then `dotnet ef database remove A`?  It should use the snapshot and not need to look at the files.

Comment: Can't you just restore the files from the recycle bin and then run "Remove-Migration" twice for A&B migration. Since they are not applied to the database you should not have any problem removing them.

Answer (score -1):

After some research, I simply executed this command to remove both A & B, even though the migration file of A has been deleted (and I didn't find it in recycle bin).

```
Remove-Migration
```

Then by using "add-migration" ef core created correct migration script.

Thank you.